# Redux State Change: UI only updates if i'm on rootPath

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I have a Reddit alike application. Where I'm trying to build out a voting function. I thought I had solved it because it workes great when on `/`

However, if I'm entering a different path `/:category` `:/category/:id`
I can see a dispatch being sent on click but here I'll have to "force update" (f5) to see a UI change.

#### API file

```
export const submitPostVote = (option, id) => {
    return axios.post(`${API_URL}/posts/${id}`, {option}, { headers })
}
```

#### Action Creator (using redux-thunk)

```
export function postPostVote(option, id) {
    const request = API.submitPostVote(option, id)

    return (dispatch) => {
        request.then(({data}) => {
            dispatch({type: SUBMIT_POST_VOTE, payload: data})
        });
    };
}
```

#### Reducer

```
export default function(state = {}, action) {
  const {payload} = action
  switch (action.type){
        case SUBMIT_POST_VOTE:
            return {...state, [payload.id]: payload}
```

#### Component that use it

```
import { postPostVote } from '../actions';

<span
 className='fa fa-angle-up voteArrow'
 onClick={() => this.props.postPostVote('upVote', id)}
></span>

export default connect(null, {postPostVote})(PostComponent);
```

#### Imported as following in other components

```
import PostComponent from './Post_PostComponent';
<div>
                <Container>
                    <PostComponent
                        key={id}
                        id={id}
                        title={title}
                        author={author}
                        voteScore={voteScore}
                        category={category}
                        timestamp={timestamp}
                        redirect={false}
                    />
                </Container>
            </div>
```

#### Repo

[Readable Repo](https://github.com/petterostergren/readable)

Comment: Is is the same component that is being used for the working and non-working route? Same container? (same `mapStateToProps` etc?)

Comment: your repo needs another project to run locally? i'm unable to clone it _Permission denied (publickey)_

Comment: Yes, it's the same component. @jonahe

Comment: @Sag1v Will take a look at that, but yes you need another project to work locally its an express server. Part of Udacity course

Comment: @Sag1v Should work to clone the server now, I had a SSH link in readme

Comment: Have you had time to test the suggested solutions yet? Any luck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i see your problem, you are using the same reducer to both of the pages.

1. The page that holds a list of items, in this case the reducer shape 
   is an object that each key is an `id` of item and it's an `object`
   as    well that holds all the data of this item.
   `{
      '6ni6ok3ym7mf1p33lnez': {
         author: "thingone",
         body: "Just kidding. It takes more than 10 minutes to learn technology.",
         category: "redux",
         deleted: false,
         id: "6ni6ok3ym7mf1p33lnez",
         timestamp: 1468479767190,
         title: "Learn Redux in 10 minutes!",
         voteScore: 6
      }
   }`
2. The page that holds a single item, in this case the very same reducer
   needs to deal with a different shape of `object` where all of the
   item's properties are spread.

`{
  author: "thingone",
  body: "Just kidding. It takes more than 10 minutes to learn technology.",
  category: "redux",
  deleted: false,
  id: "6ni6ok3ym7mf1p33lnez",
  timestamp: 1468479767190,
  title: "Learn Redux in 10 minutes!",
  voteScore: 6
}`

Just for example, if you will change the shape of the object that your `reducer_posts.js` returns:
From this:

```
case SUBMIT_POST_VOTE:
            return {...state, [payload.id]: payload}
```

To this:

```
case SUBMIT_POST_VOTE:
            return {...state, ...payload}
```

You will notice that now the first page with the list not working well but the second page that shows the single item is working as expected.

So you should re-think the shape of your reducers or split this reducer into two.

**EDIT**
I was curious on what will be the best structure to handle this scenario so i took the liberty of changing some stuff for you.

So I've decided to split your `reducer_posts.js` into 2 reducers:
`posts` and `post` (plural and singular).
I've added another reducer `reducer_post.js`.
and this is the code:

```
import { POST_GET_POST, SUBMIT_POST_VOTE } from '../actions/action_constants';

export default function (state = {}, action) {
    const { payload } = action
    switch (action.type) {
        case SUBMIT_POST_VOTE:
            return { ...state, ...payload }
        case POST_GET_POST:
            return payload;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

And the old reducer `reducer_posts.js` now looks like this:

```
import _ from 'lodash';
import { POST_GET_POSTS, SUBMIT_POST_VOTE } from '../actions/action_constants';

export default function(state = {}, action) {
  const {payload} = action
  switch (action.type){
        case SUBMIT_POST_VOTE:
            return {...state, [payload.id]: payload}
        case POST_GET_POSTS:
      return _.mapKeys(payload, 'id');
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

And of course don't forget to add it to the `rootReducer`:

```
export const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  routing: routerReducer,
  posts: PostsReducer,
  post: PostReducer, // our new reducer
    comments: CommentReducer,
  categories: CategoriesReducer,
});
```

Basically one will handle multiple posts object shape and one will handle a single post object shape.

Now, the only thing you should change is the `mapStateToProps` in the `Post_DetailedPost.js` component.
Instead of using the `posts` reducer it will use the `post` reducer:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {post: state.post}
}
```

This should fix your problem.

Comment: Haha, I posted the same (ish) findings just  a few tens of seconds after you. But if you have run the code and seen the actual shape of the data you probably have more accurate examples.

Comment: Hehe, iv'e noticed it when i was looking at the source code but i had to run it to be 100% sure :)

Comment: Really interesting comments that I had not thought about, this worked out great. I will review my code again and this comment to really understand what I was doing wrong. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is this: The reducer logic for the vote action assumes that the state has some specific structure to it ( an object with posts, with their id as the key.), but then the reducer logic for the getPost action breaks this assumption.

Looked at the code in the repo, specifically for the "DetailedPost". This looked a bit off, but I may be wrong:

```js
// in reducer_posts.js
case POST_GET_POST:**strong text**
  return payload;
```

I would think that you get one specfic post from the API. If so, this return would basically get rid of everything else in the state. (All other posts). Maybe that's what you want, but I've never seen a reducer change the structure of the state in that way. I would have expected it to be something like

```js
case POST_GET_POST:
  return {...state, [payload.id]: payload}
```

(maybe without the `...state` if you really want the rest of the posts to disappear.).

But then you'd have to change the `mapStateToProps` for the detailed view  as well. You should be able to access the Router props from the second argument (Note: exact path on `ownProps` may be different. I don't remember exactly how the url params where stored)

```js
// in Post_DetailedPost.js
function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
    const idFromURL =  ownProps.id; // or maybe ownProps.match.params.id
    return {post: state.posts[idFromURL]};
}
```

This could actually very well be the issue, because you upvote a post, you get the new (updated) post back, and you change the state like this.

```js
case SUBMIT_POST_VOTE:
            return {...state, [payload.id]: payload}
```

But that's not the state structure that your used to pass the post down down to your component. So you wouldn't get the updated props passed down to the details view. (But with the suggested edits to the `mapStateToProps` it might work.)

Comment: This was also a really good approach. Thanks for pointing out the issues